# Modify Django Admin Page

Tags: django, admin, z-index

I have a django admin where the name for the login was changed and after logging in the page is cut off. I went in to modify the page but it appears there is no admin/index under templates. I have looked throughout the project and can not find it anywhere. Is there an easy way to locate the files needed to proceed with the project?

Comment: The django admin templates are in your django module under `contrib/admin/templates/`. But do not edit the source. Copy the ones you need to modify into your own template folder order [extend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to locate the contrib folder. I believe that folder should be under project_name/project_name/contrib.

Comment: No it's not in your project folder. It's usually in a folder called site-packages where pip places all your installed modules. If you are using `virtualenv`you will find it in your env folder.

Comment: Is it an issue if I looked under site-packages under my python version and found no files?

Comment: Does this hold true for the modified template when in that contrib folder when pulled in from github?

Comment: You should provide a little bit more info in your question. How did you change the admin login name and why? Post some code of your view and maybe your urls. This will make it much easier to help you. It may not be necessary to override the admin templates. If you really need to you can find more about overriding admin templates [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)

Comment: Hi. I know how to override the page. However, I took over this site with no access to the original developer. I searched the repo and can not find it as well. I can see what I can provide.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "the site is cut off"? What makes you think that the problem is in the template? How does your urls.py look like? Without some more context it will be impossible to help you.